# Google Ads Query parameter variation

Tags: url, parameters, ads

I would like to vary URL parameters in my Google Ads ad. Currently, my campaign consists of a single ad pointing to a landing page (e.g., /landing/landing-name). This landing page contains two parameters, "title" and "cta," that I want to vary at the Google Ads ad level to display different content based on the defined URL. However, I am struggling to find a way to pass a parameter that can take a value from 0 to x in Google Ads.